# QTP How to save images from webpages

Tags: image, vbscript, qtp

I would like to know if it's possible to simulate the process: Right click on an image -> Click on "Save image as.." on the popup menu -> save the image in local.

I tried CaptureBitmap() function, but the result is just a screenshot taken by QTP, not the same image file obtained as the procedure above.

Are there other ways? Many thanks in advance.

Allen

Comment: Allen, I had another thought, please check out my answer and see if it works for you.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I suppose it depends what you want to do. If you want to compare the bitmap then the `CaptureBitmap` options should work. If you want to compare the path to the image you can use `Image("x").GetROProperty("src")`.

If you really want to save the `src` image file then unfortunately QTP doesn't supply a way to interact with the browser's context menu. You can try to use some third-party mechanism to download the image from the `src` URL (e.g. [wget](http://www.gnu.org/s/wget/)).

---

**Edit:** I just had another thought, I'm not at work so I can't verify that it will work but I'm pretty sure it will.

First cause the context menu to appear, in order to do this you have to change the replay mode to device and run a `RightClick` operation.

```
 replayType = Setting.WebPackage("ReplayType") ' Store old replay mode
 Setting.WebPackage("ReplayType") = 2 ' change to device replay mode
 Browser("b").Page("p").Image("I").RightClick
 Setting.WebPackage("ReplayType") = replayType ' Revert to old mode
```

Then send the letter <kbd>v</kbd> to the browser which will select the `Save` menu item (on both IE and Firefox) by using the [device replay object](http://www.advancedqtp.com/2008/04/the-undocumented-devicereplay/)

```
Set deviceReplay = CreateObject( “Mercury.DeviceReplay” )
deviceReplay.SendString "v"
```

Now interact with the save dialog as a usual Win32 control.

*Moral:* Never underestimate what QTP will let you do if you try hard enough

Comment: @allenzzzxd, don't you want to wait a bit with accepting this answer till you see that nothing better comes along?

Comment: Well, thanks for your advice. I'll wait a bit longer. But basing on my research on this subject, I hardly found nothing more helpful...